# Showing a subspace of continuous function is dense in the whole space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> For any topological space $X$, $C(X)$ denote the space of continuous functions from $X \to \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the uniform norm $\Vert f\Vert_u=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$.

> $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra if $\mathscr{A}$ is a subspace of the vector space $C(X)$ such that $fg\in \mathscr{A}$ for all $f,g\in \mathscr{A}$.

Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. Show that the algebra generated by functions of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ where $g,h \in C(X),C(Y)$ respectively,  is dense in $C(X \times Y)$.

What I want to show, I think is $\overline{A}=C(X \times Y)$ where $A$ is the algebra generated by the above function $f$. First I show $\overline{A}\subset C(X \times Y)$, which is pretty straightforward, note that $f\in \mathbb{R}^{X\times Y}$ so all we need to show is $f$ is continuous on $X \times Y$ and the closure is continuous since the uniform limit of continuous function is continuous, and it $f$ can be shown with $\epsilon/2$ from the continuity of $g,h$.

The converse is where I am not able to construct any solution, I would assume I start with a $f \in C(X \times Y)$ and construct a sequence in $A$ that converges to $f$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to construct a such sequence of functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Stone-Weierstrass-theorem?

Comment: @PaulFrost Ah I see, then the solution to the question only requires me to show $A$ is a closed subalgebra and then I am done since $A$ contains constant functions?

Comment: Yes. You should write an answer to your own quesetion. Don't forget that $A$ separates points.